# When Installing polyglot with pip exception: Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in

Tags: python, installation, polyglot

I am trying to install polyglot. I run Windows10 and have installed python3 using Anaconda3.

I have updated the setuptools.

The command and the error message are the following:

```
(base) C:\Users\Alienware\Documents>pip install -U git+https://github.com/aboSamoor/polyglot.git@master

Collecting git+https://github.com/aboSamoor/polyglot.git@master
  Cloning https://github.com/aboSamoor/polyglot.git (to revision master) to c:\users\alienw~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-req-build-qt6pounr
Collecting PyICU>=1.8 (from polyglot==16.7.4)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/c2/15/0af20b540c828943b6ffea5677c86e908dcac108813b522adebb75c827c1/PyICU-2.2.tar.gz (211kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 215kB 789kB/s
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\ALIENW~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-8fgenlih\PyICU\setup.py", line 43, in <module>
        ICU_VERSION = os.environ['ICU_VERSION']
      File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\os.py", line 669, in __getitem__
        raise KeyError(key) from None
    KeyError: 'ICU_VERSION'

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\ALIENW~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-8fgenlih\PyICU\setup.py", line 46, in <module>
        ICU_VERSION = check_output(('icu-config', '--version')).strip()
      File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 336, in check_output
        **kwargs).stdout
      File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 403, in run
        with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
      File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 707, in __init__
        restore_signals, start_new_session)
      File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 992, in _execute_child
        startupinfo)
    FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\ALIENW~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-8fgenlih\PyICU\setup.py", line 53, in <module>
        ''')
    RuntimeError:
    Please set the ICU_VERSION environment variable to the version of
    ICU you have installed.


    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\ALIENW~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-8fgenlih\PyICU\
```

Comment: Observed that this package have had previous compatibility versions. https://github.com/aboSamoor/polyglot/issues/117  Which version of python3 are you using ?

Comment: Python 3.6.2 :: Anaconda custom (64-bit)